# Show/Hide submit button depending on selected value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I would like to show/hide additional submit button depending on selected value in form.
I have no experience with JavaScript so I have only tried to modify examples found on web.
 
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything related with rails `form_for`.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<%= form_for @discount, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %><br />
    <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Description" %><br />
    <%= f.label :with_codes, "Type" %><br />
    <%= f.select :with_codes, [['Without Codes', false],['With Codes', true]], :selected => :with_codes %><br />

    <div id="row_dim">
        <%= f.submit "Manage Codes" %><br />
    </div>

      <script>
          $(function() {
              $('#row_dim').hide();
              $('#with_codes').change(function(){
                  if($('#with_codes').val() == true) {
                      $('#row_dim').show();
                  } else {
                      $('#row_dim').hide();
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>

    <%= f.submit "Draft" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

This script only hides my submit button, but I think there is a problem with recognizing selected value in form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: are you sure that the select has id `with_codes` and not `discount_with_codes`?

Second thing, you should compare the value of the select as a string. Taking these two issues into account, the following code should work:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     $('#row_dim').hide();
     $('#discount_with_codes').change(function(){
       if($('#discount_with_codes').val() == 'true') {
         $('#row_dim').show();
       } else {
         $('#row_dim').hide();
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that model is part of field_id. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe like this (more concise):

```
$(function() {
  $("#row_dim").toggle($("#discount_with_codes").val() == 'true');
  $("#discount_with_codes").change(function() {
    $("#row_dim").toggle($(this).val() == 'true');
  });
});
```

**EDIT**: Whoops, looks like you've already accepted the answer. But I'll leave mine here anyway.

Comment: As I see your solution is better. Because it won't auto hide button in edit form. Thank you :)

Comment: You'd get the same result with accepted answer by @pmichna, only adding condition around `$("#row_dim").hide()`. But he basically answered your question perfectly (boolean values as strings), and that's what it was all about. My solution is only a bit more compact ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
 function(){
   $('#row_dim').hide();
   $('#with_codes').change(function() {
      if($('#with_codes').val() == true)
      {
        $('#row_dim').show();
      } 
      else
      {
        $('#row_dim').hide();
      }
   });
 }()
</script>
```